# publish up wifi

Tags: ros, wifi, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i can't puplish mesage up wifi ..
can you help me ?
sorry I don't speak English  well.
thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192246/publish-up-wifi/) by [turtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/20154/turtle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2014-09-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-09-09**:
If you provide more information we can help you.

**Comment by [turtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/20154/turtle/) on 2014-09-09**:
thank you
i just can publish mesage in my pc
i can't publish to other pc in LAN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to set up a wifi access point and set that as the ros master.
You probably want to set this access point in your robot which has roscore running and connect to its network with your laptop.
More info on how to make a ros master here: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup

**EDIT**

1. Figure out where roscore is running in. (It is probably in your robot)
2. Set up a single wireless network. (In your case if the robot has the roscore running you want to set up a wireless access point in the robot and connect to the wireless network with your computer)
3. Configure the Ros master URI so that you can see all of the ros topics in your computer: info here http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup (you need to edit the robot's .bashrc and your computers .bashrc according to the wiki)

---

Originally posted by [goshawk](https://answers.ros.org/users/18870/goshawk/) with karma: 70 on 2014-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [turtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/20154/turtle/) on 2014-09-09**:
thank you , i'll try

**Comment by [turtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/20154/turtle/) on 2014-09-09**:
Can you repeat clearly,please

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-09-11**:
I want to add: The position of the access point can be everywhere. Master and clients have to be in the same subnet only.

**Comment by [turtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/20154/turtle/) on 2014-09-12**:
thank you.. i done ! @@

**Comment by [goshawk](https://answers.ros.org/users/18870/goshawk/) on 2014-09-12**:
Great!!!!!